# SIMULINK/dSPACE: Manual start of real-time simulation input data

Tags: matlab, simulink, dspace-ecu

Good day everyone,
I am using a dSPACE interface connected to my test set-up in order to facilitate a real-time working environment.

When a model is built and loaded onto the dSPACE module, dSPACE immediately excites the defined signals on the test set-up. However, the switch between modes is not instantaneous and thus there is a delay in the logging procedure.

To enable the logging from the start (t = 0), I tried to get control of the manual activation of input signals by using the 'From Workspace'-block of SIMULINK in an Enabled Subsystem. However, when the subsystem is activated at a time instance (say: t = 3s), the output signal of this block is read from the 'From Workspace'-block at that time instance (so from t = 3s, not t = 0s). So, in this case I am always missing a part of an input signal in the beginning of my experiment.

So:

- Any suggestions on what SIMULINK-blocks can be used to facilitate this manual activation of input signals?
- How to accomplish that the data logging starts immediately after the application starts on the dSPACE module?

Comment: so, If I understand you correctly, just load your data not in Enabled Subsystem - load all dataset and use it just in time (at t = 3s).

Comment: What is the purpose of your initial delay? The standard solution would be to download your application in a paused or stopped state, configure it and start it then manually.

Comment: When the application is loaded onto the dSPACE-module, the application starts to run, whereas the logging procedure only starts when I switch to 'Animation Mode'. The actual delay for switching between modes is smaller than three seconds; this duration is caused by my current SIMULINK design to bypass the immediate read-action from the 'From Workspace'-block.

Comment: "When the application is loaded onto the dSPACE-module, the application starts to run,"  that is not true. When you download an application it will enter the initial state you have specified. Set it to pause or stop before downloading, download, set the animation mode, start.